# How to render props in react components while using react-router-dom version 6

Tags: reactjs, components, react-router-dom, render

```
 return (
   <div className="ui container">
     <Router>
        <Header />
           <Routes>
             <Route path="/"
                exact element={() => {
                  <ContactList contacts={contacts}
                    agetContactId={removeContactHandler} />}}> 
           </Route>
           <Route path="/add" element={() => { <AddContact /> }}> </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As the heading suggests , I am using the version 6 of react-router-dom and I am not able to render   ContactList props ie contacts={contacts} and agetContactId={removeContactHandler}. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you are not returning anything inside function you provided to `element` prop of the `<Route />`.

This should work:

```
return (
   <div className="ui container">
     <Router>
        <Header />
           <Routes>
             <Route path="/"
                exact element={
                  <ContactList contacts={contacts}
                    agetContactId={removeContactHandler} />}> 
           </Route>
           <Route path="/add" element={<AddContact />}> </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also there is no need to pass function, you can pass JSX directly to the `element` prop.